# If there is a inclusion of restrictions, then is there an inclusion of sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be the projective space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $H$ be a smooth hyperplane in $X$. Let $F$ and $G$ be torsion-free sheaves on $X$ of rank 1 and 2 respectively such that we have an inclusion $F|_H\subset G|_H$. Does this mean that $F$ is a subsheaf of $G$? If these are torsion sheaves, I can see that this need not be true. But in this case will this be true?

Comment: Do you assume a map $F \to G$ a priori and ask if this is injective, if its injective after restriction to $H$?

Comment: @MooS, No I don't have such a map as such. I just have an inclusion between the restriction. It seems to be too much to ask for.

Comment: My answer deals with the case, where such a map is given. If such a map is not given, we have no chance I guess.

Comment: @Moos, so now the question is if the map $F|_H\rightarrow G|_H$ on the hyperplane can be extended to a morphism on the projective space

Comment: Yes, this is what remains.

Answer (score 3):

In general this is false. For example, take the projective plane, $F=\mathcal{O}$ and $G$ a rank two stable bundle of determinant zero. Then $H^0(G)=0$, so there is no inclusion of $F$ in $G$. But, for a general line $H$, $G_{|H}=\mathcal{O}_H^2$.

Comment: Nice example, I guessed that this cannot be true in general.

Comment: @Mohan,@MooS maybe if I impose a stronger condition that $F|_H\subset G|_H$ for every hyperplane $H$?

Comment: No, here is an easy counterexample: Take $X$ to be the projective line, $F$ the structure sheaf and $G$ the direct sum of two copies of $\mathcal O(-1)$. Restricted to any closed point, $F$ and $G$ are just vector spaces of rank 1 and 2, i.e. there is an inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Are $F,G$ coherent? If not, this is clearly false:

Consider $R=K[X], f=X, F=K(X), G=K[X] \oplus K[X]$ and let $F \to G$ be the zero map, which is cleary not injective. We have $F/fF=0$, i.e. the map is injective after tensoring with $R/f$.

If $F$ is coherent and $G$ is quasi-coherent, it is true:

The assertion local, so we can reduce to the affine case and have to show the following:

> $R$ is the polynomial ring and $f \in R$, $M$ and $N$ some
>   torsion-free sheaves with a map $M \to N$. Furthermore $M$ is finitely
>   generated.
>
> If the induced map $M/fM \to N/fN$ is injective, then $M \to N$ was
>   injective.

Note that we can assume $f$ to be irreducible (If not, we further restrict to an irreducible component of $H$), i.e. $P=(f)$ is a prime of height $1$.
We also can assume the map to be surjective, since we can replace $N$ be the image (which is still torsion-free).

Let $K$ be the kernel of $M \to N$. $K$ is torsion-free, hence it is injected in any of its localizations. In particular $K$ is zero iff $K_P=0$.

Thus it suffices to show that $M_P \to N_P$ is injective. Look at the exact sequence

$$0 \to K_P \to M_P \to N_P \to 0.$$

All terms are torsion-free and $R_P$ is a Dedekind ring, hence all terms are flat. Thus the sequence stays exact after tensoring with $R_P/f$:

$$0 \to K_P/fK_p \to M_P/fM_P \to N_P/fM_P \to 0.$$

By assumption the second map is injective, hence $K_P/fK_p=0$, i.e. $K_P=fK_P$. Nakayama implies $K_P=0$. We can use Nakayama, since $K$ is finitely generated, because it is a submodule of $M$ and $M$ is finitely generated over a noetherian ring.

Comment: this is  great! $F$ and $G$ are indeed coherent sheaves. But I don't per say have a map from $F\rightarrow G$, but you have assumed there is a map from $M\rightarrow N$ right